# Geopy, pandas, FOR loop fail

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, geopy

I am teaching myself `geopy`. It seems simple and straightforward yet my code isn't working. It is supposed to:

- read in a list of address field from a CSV into a `pandas` df
- concatenate the address fields into a single column formatted for `geopy`
- make a list from the new column
- feed each item in the list into `geopy` via a for loop and return the coordinates add the
  coordinates to the original df and export it to a CSV

```
    #setup
    from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
    import pandas as pd
        
    #create the df
    df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('properties to geocode.csv'))
    df['Location'] = df['Street Address'].astype(str)+","+df['City'].astype(str)+","+df['State'].astype(str)
        
    #create the geolocator object
    geolocator = Nominatim(timeout=1, user_agent = "My_Agent")
        
    #create the locations list
    locations = df['Location']
        
    #empty lists for later columns
    lats = []
    longs = []
        
    #process the location list
    for item in locations: 
        location = geolocator.geocode('item')
        lat =  location.latitude
        long = location.longitude
        lats.append(lat)
        longs.append(long)
        
    #add the lists to the df
    df.insert(5,'Latitude',lats)
    df.insert(6,'Longitude',longs)
        
    #export
    df.to_csv('geocoded-properties2.csv',index=False)
```

Something is not working because it returns the same latitude and longitude values for every row, instead of unique coordinates for each.

I have found working code using .apply elsewhere but am interested in learning what I did wrong.  Any thoughts?

Comment: `location = geolocator.geocode('item')` you are passing string literal,  not the value of the variable **item**

Comment: Thanks for your reply. when I remove the ' ' around item I get the following error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'latitude'

Comment: I've provided a more extensive answer.  If you provide an address that is not found `geolocator.geocode()` returns `None`.  This is explicitly tested for in function I wrote before it returns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- your code does not contain sample data.  Have used some sample data available from public APIs to demonstrate
- your code passes a literal to `geolocator.geocode()` - it needs to be the address associated with the row
- have provided example of using with **pandas** `apply`, a **list comprehension** and a `for` loop equivalent of a **comprehension**
- results show all three approaches are equivalent

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import requests
import pandas as pd

searchendpoint = "https://directory.spineservices.nhs.uk/ORD/2-0-0/organisations"
# get all healthcare facilities in Herefordshire
dfhc = pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(requests
                             .get(searchendpoint, params={"PostCode":f"HR{i}","Status":"Active"})
                             .json()["Organisations"]) 
           for i in range(1,10)]).reset_index(drop=True)

def gps(url, geolocator=None):
    # get the address and construct a space delimted string
    a = " ".join(str(x) for x in requests.get(url).json()["Organisation"]["GeoLoc"]["Location"].values())
    lonlat = geolocator.geocode(a)
    if not lonlat is None:
        return lonlat[1]
    else:
        return (0,0)

# work with just GPs
dfgp = dfhc.loc[dfhc.PrimaryRoleId.isin(["RO180","RO96"])].head(5).copy()

geolocator = Nominatim(timeout=1, user_agent = "My_Agent")


# pandas apply
dfgp["lonlat_apply"] = dfgp["OrgLink"].apply(gps, geolocator=geolocator)

# list comprehension
lonlat = [gps(url, geolocator=geolocator) for url in dfgp["OrgLink"].values]
dfgp["lonlat_listcomp"] = lonlat

# old school loop
lonlat = []
for item in dfgp["OrgLink"].values:
    lonlat.append(gps(item, geolocator=geolocator))
dfgp["lonlat_oldschool"] = lonlat
```

|  | Name | OrgId | Status | OrgRecordClass | PostCode | LastChangeDate | PrimaryRoleId | PrimaryRoleDescription | OrgLink | lonlat_apply | lonlat_listcomp | lonlat_oldschool |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | AYLESTONE HILL SURGERY | M81026002 | Active | RC2 | HR1 1HR | 2020-03-19 | RO96 | BRANCH SURGERY | https://directory.spineservices.nhs.uk/ORD/2-0-0/organisations/M81026002 | (52.0612429, -2.7026047) | (52.0612429, -2.7026047) | (52.0612429, -2.7026047) |
| 9 | BARRS COURT SCHOOL | 5CN91 | Active | RC2 | HR1 1EQ | 2021-01-28 | RO180 | PRIMARY CARE TRUST SITE | https://directory.spineservices.nhs.uk/ORD/2-0-0/organisations/5CN91 | (52.0619209, -2.7086105) | (52.0619209, -2.7086105) | (52.0619209, -2.7086105) |
| 13 | BODENHAM SURGERY | 5CN24 | Active | RC2 | HR1 3JU | 2013-05-08 | RO180 | PRIMARY CARE TRUST SITE | https://directory.spineservices.nhs.uk/ORD/2-0-0/organisations/5CN24 | (52.152405, -2.6671942) | (52.152405, -2.6671942) | (52.152405, -2.6671942) |
| 22 | BELMONT ABBEY | 5CN16 | Active | RC2 | HR2 9RP | 2013-05-08 | RO180 | PRIMARY CARE TRUST SITE | https://directory.spineservices.nhs.uk/ORD/2-0-0/organisations/5CN16 | (52.0423056, -2.7648698) | (52.0423056, -2.7648698) | (52.0423056, -2.7648698) |
| 24 | BELMONT HEALTH CENTRE | 5CN22 | Active | RC2 | HR2 7XT | 2013-05-08 | RO180 | PRIMARY CARE TRUST SITE | https://directory.spineservices.nhs.uk/ORD/2-0-0/organisations/5CN22 | (52.0407746, -2.739788) | (52.0407746, -2.739788) | (52.0407746, -2.739788) |